# Hit detection between two image objects in processing not working. Looking to decrease player life upon collision

Tags: processing

this part is just for context of the game, I don't think it's needed to solve the question but I'm not too sure:

```
boolean intro=true;
boolean end=false;
PImage asteroid_1;
PImage cover;

int lives =3;

class Sprite { 
  float x;
  float y;
  float dx;
  float dy; 
  color asteroidcolor;
  color lasercolor;
}

Sprite player= new Sprite();
Sprite roid= new Sprite();
Sprite laser=new Sprite();

class Asteroids extends Sprite {
  float speedmultiplier;
  float speedupposition;
  color asteroidcolor;
  String state; // "entering", "moving", "speed up"

  void randomRestart(){
    x= random(500,650);
    y= random(50,550);
    speedmultiplier= random(1.10,1.5);
    dx= random(1.5,2.5);
    dy= 0;
    speedupposition= random(300,450);
    asteroidcolor= color(50,40,18);
    state = "entering";    
  }

  void render(){
    pushMatrix();
    if(state.equals("entering")){
      image(asteroid_1, x,y);
    }
    else if(state.equals("speed up")){
      fill(asteroidcolor);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x,y,50,50);
    }

//    else if(state.equals("hit")){
      //translate(x,y);
//      fill(hitcolor);
//      noStroke();
//      ellipse(x,y,50,50);
//   }
    else if (state.equals("restart")){
       translate(x,y); 
       fill(asteroidcolor);
       noStroke();
       ellipse(x,y,50,50);
    }

    popMatrix();
  }

  void update(){
  if (state.equals("entering")){
    x += -dx;
    if (state.equals("speed up")){
  x += -dx * speedmultiplier;
  }
  }
    if (x < -100 || x > width + 100){
      state ="restart";
      randomRestart();    
      }
  }
    }



Asteroids randomAsteroids(){
  Asteroids roid = new Asteroids();
    roid.x= random(550,650);
    roid.y= random(50,550);
    roid.speedmultiplier= random(1.10,2.0);
    roid.dx= random(1.5,3.0);
    roid.dy= 0;
    roid.speedupposition= random(300,450);
    roid.asteroidcolor= color(50,40,18);
    roid.asteroidcolor= color(50,50,50); 
    return roid;
}
```

declaring the variables used in the collision later on:

```
ArrayList<Asteroids> roidsList;
PImage jet;
float playerX= 50;
float playerY= 250;
float playerWidth= 74;
float playerHeight= 59;

float roidX= random(550,650);
float roidY= random(50,550);
float roidXSpeed= 3;
float roidYSpeed=0;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  player.x = 50;
  player.y= 250;
  player.dx=0;
  player.dy=20.5; 
  jet= loadImage("player.png");
  roid.x= random(550,650);
  roid.y= random(50,550);
  roid.asteroidcolor= color(50,40,18); 
  laser.x=30;
  laser.y=10;
  laser.dx= 1.5;
  laser.dy=0;
  laser.lasercolor= color(50,40,18);
  cover = loadImage("3.png");

  roidsList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();

  int i = 0;
  while (i<15){
   Asteroids a = new Asteroids();
   a.randomRestart();
    roidsList.add    (a);
    ++i;
  }
}
```

attempt at collision detection below.:

```
void draw(){
  background(30,30,60);
  fill(0,0,0);
  noStroke();
  image(jet, player.x, player.y);
  player.x += player.dx;
  text("lives left:"+lives, 10, 20);

  for (Asteroids b : roidsList){
    b.render();
    b.update();
  }  

  if(intro){
    image (cover,0,0);
    }

  if(intersectsPlayer(roidX+roidXSpeed, roidY)){
    lives=lives-1;
  } 

  roidX += roidXSpeed;
}  
  boolean intersectsPlayer(float x, float y){
    if (x>playerX && x<playerX+playerWidth){
      if (y > playerY && y< playerY+ playerHeight){
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}



void keyPressed(){
  intro=false;
  if (key =='w'){//up
  player.y += -player.dy;
    if(player.y < -2){
    player.y =-2;
    }
  }
  if (key =='s'){
  player.y += player.dy;
    if (player.y >442){
    player.y=442;
  }
  }
  if (key==' '){
  rect(player.x,player.y+50,laser.x, laser.y, 3);
  fill(255,0,0);
  }
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Which line doesn't work the way you expected it to?

Comment: Within void draw(), I can't figure out the following portion on making it work with collision detection.  

 boolean intersectsPlayer(float x, float y){
    if (x>playerX && x<playerX+playerWidth){
      if (y > playerY && y< playerY+ playerHeight){
      return true;
    }
  }


x being the horizontal position for the roid, and playerX being the horizontal position for the player (and same for Y).  

I've also tried:
   if ((roidX >= playerX && roidX<= playerX+playerWidth) &&
   (roidY >= playerY && roidY<= playerY+playerHeight)){
   lives = lives-1;
   } else{
   }